# Как убрать сообщение "Confirm Form Resubmission" при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html

Пишу сайт, при входе попадаю на главную страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при перезагрузке выскакивает сообщение **"Confirm Form Resubmission"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например когда сразу после авторизации в ВК перезагружаешь страницу, подобного сообщения не выскакивает.

Подскажите - что можно сделать чтобы страница не просила повторной отправки формы при перезагрузке?

Если важны детали реализации - они [здесь](https://github.com/ReijiAkkerman/native_project.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Обработка данных после отправки формы


    // После обработки данных, выполните перенаправление
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Простой способ предотвратить повторную отправку формы в PHP

Comment: это может решить проблему но не в авторизации, когда я авторизовываю пользователя мне необходимо установить в браузере клиента куки чтобы не запрашивать у пользователя каждый раз пароль, тут то и возникает проблема ведь функция `setcookie()` бесполезна если в конце скрипта будет `header("...some code...")`.

Comment: "функция setcookie() бесполезна если" что за бред? Почему она бесполезна?

Comment: @u_mulder когда используестся сначала `setcookie()` а затем `header('Location: ...some_path...')` куки до пользователя не доходят. Видимо из-за того что скрипт начинает работать заново с новыми аргументами (по крайней мере у меня apache перенаправляет любой запрос на корневой index.php) все значения до перенаправления обнуляются(в том числе куки которые должны были уйти клиенту). Не просто же так в документации к `header()`-функции пишут *Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.*

Comment: @u_mulder видимо логика сайта не давала устанавливать куки. на супер простом примере куки установились)) Спасибо вам) Буду двигаться дальше